# AS3 How to architect a tablet app that only needs to connect to a laptop to update content?

Tags: android, actionscript-3, apache-flex

I've built apps that connect to a server. But this time a client has asked for an app with no need to connect to a server to update content (images,videos,text).

It will be Android tablet to a Windows laptop via USB. It will be for end user no dragging and dropping into specific folders using USB debugging.

I was thinking I may need to build an app for the laptop (content manager) and then the app for tablet.
Is a framework out there that could jump start this?
Thanks

Comment: Any reason you need to use usb? You could use sockets over a network connection

Comment: The scenario is at a tradeshow where there may not be any wifi available. The user would manage content given to him on his laptop such as a 3 min video, but needs to do a quick edit to only use 30 sec. Are you maybe suggesting creating a local wifi connection between a laptop and tablet? USB transfer would quick and simple. Its for end user usage so I'm thinking of building the ui and procedures as simple as possible. :)

Comment: I would look into setting up a local network. You could set up a wireless router and use sockets over that. No need to be connected to the internet. I don't think you're going to be able to do real time data transfer over usb in AIR without a ton of trouble

Comment: Sorry it would better if the files were copied over to the tablet so it would play from itself. No routers. Remember the end user capabilities when it comes to devices let alone a router. I think I need to start playing with it and see where I end up with it. I need to get a quote to the client so I was researching if this had been done before. I agree with the local network streaming but what if the laptop goes missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can setup a batch script that runs some adb commands when the tablet is plugged in. Then you could use 'adb push' to push some update files onto the tablet, and the app could check for these files when it runs and take appropriate actions with them.

Comment: This is probably the best workflow for the simple end-user. I need to make the UI and workflow as simple as possible. Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 0):

This would probably be best as a desktop application (not an Android app). The tablet's SDCard is already mountable as a USB mass storage device, so why not just have a desktop application mount that drive, move the files into the correct folder, and eject the drive? Then when the tablet app is opened, the new files are there.